# A set of vectors forming the basis

Tags: vector-spaces

Can:

(b) A set of four vectors: {(1,2,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(1,3,2)}

form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (but equivalent) method for checking whether three given vectors
in $R^3$ span the space is to check whether the determinant of the matrix formed
by arranging them in rows (or columns) is non-zero. It is my opinion that it is easier to remember how to calculate a $3\times 3$ determinant than a scalar triple product, although they are precisely the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need three non-coplanare vectors to form a basis in three dimensions. To test if they are non-coplanar, calculate the scalar triple product, which should be non-zero